# Alinhamento do texto «Registrar-se» quebrado no botão da página de criação de conta

Tags: bug, layout

Vi agora a pouco um problema na página de cadastro.

Quando você vai criar uma nova conta manualmente, o botão «Registrar-se» está com a frase *"desalinhada"* (não consigo pensar em uma palavra melhor para isso). Podem ver melhor com a imagem, ou [ver por si mesmos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/signup?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fpt.stackoverflow.com%2f) (tem que estar deslogado).

Isso ocorreu no Chrome 60, mas testei e pode ser visto no Mozilla também.

#### Chrome

[image: Print do Problema no Chrome]

#### Mozilla

[image: Print do Problema no Mozilla]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Só pra constar, o problema **não é** no `text-align`, mas sim no `padding` combinado com o `width: 120px;`

```css
#add-login-page input[type=button], #login-page input[type=button], #signup-page input[type=button], #add-login-page input[type=submit], #login-page input[type=submit], #signup-page input[type=submit] {
    text-align: center;
    background: #07C;
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 12px 40px; <--- aqui
    box-shadow: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

Se fizer isto ele volta ao "normal":

```
    padding: 12px 0; <--- aqui
```

No entanto creio que o `padding-left` e `padding-right` com 40px tenha alguma motivação para um dos outros seletores, então pode talvez remover o `width`, ou criar uma exceção na cascata do CSS.

No entanto vou deixar isto para o *staff* resolver, afinal eles conhecem as necessidades e os "porques", só quis adiantar e ajudar a apontar a origem do problema.